# Profiling iOS app with Instruments fails: No allocated PMI record error

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

I'd like to profile my app using Instruments App.

My app is built without an error. I built it with `Product > Profile` menu.
[image]

After the build is finished, the Instruments app is automatically launched.
I select the CPU Profiler template, and click record button to start the profile.

[image]

But the app couldn't even start because the Instruments says that

> No allocated PMI Record

What's worse is that after this message, my iPhone is bricked, and I have to forcefully reboot the device.

I've searched the google but there aren't any useful explanation regarding this message.

I'm wondering:

1. what this "PMI" mean
2. why this message show up

If anyone happens to have any clue, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.
Instruments Version 14.0.1 (14A400)
iOS 16.1
iPhone 14 Pro Max

Comment: Still Instruments 15.2